# Create a php uploader, in order to interrupt the loading of the uploading file

Tags: php, size, uploader

I would like to know if it’s possible to create a php uploader, in order to interrupt the  loading of the uploading file, once XX bytes are loaded on the server.
I.e
I’m uploading an heavy file, but I need only the info saved on the first 24kb of that file.
Is it possible to create an upload in order to save only the first 24kb of that file and shut down that entire upload once that 24kb are loaded and read from the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once i used following solution

1. Uploaded via POST file is stored in tmp folder
2. Simple script opens files and reads only necessary data from beginning

   ```
   $upload_file = fopen("tmp/your_uploaded_file", "r")
   $temp_file = fopen("your_folder/file_to_be_written", "w");   
   while ($data = fread($upload_data, your_buffer_size)) 
      fwrite($temp_file, $data);
   fclose($temp_file);
   fclose($upload_data);
   ```
3. Shell script deletes file in tmp folder from time to time

Not the best one, but works)

Comment: Also I forgot to mention about some variable in php.ini used for file uploads: max_file_uploads, upload_max_size, post_max_size. The last two can be set in Megabytes (say 10M). Check them